# Can an SSL certificate be signed by two issuers at the same time?

Tags: tls, root

Can an SSL certificate be signed by two issuers at the same time?

Let's take an intermediate certificate as an example.

It is usually signed by a root. A root certificate is often self-signed.
In my understanding, if we take cross-signing, there are usually two or more certificate sets as we have several intermediate or root variations signed by different roots.

I have never seen a certificate signed by several issuers at the same time in practice.
Is it possible?

---

P.S. I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/477426/certificates-signed-by-multiple-cas

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506068/can-a-ssl-certificate-be-signed-by-multiple-certificate-authorities

https://superuser.com/questions/1013159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-certificate-signed-by-2-authorities

No, it's not possible for an X.509 certificate (the type used by OpenSSL) to have more than one signature.

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: yes, and it's called "cross-signing".